# Log4j doesn't logging custom logs through Slf4j

Tags: java, logging

I try to add logging through `Slf4j`.

I have added dependencies:

```
        //log4j
        // log4j-slf4j-impl
        implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.17.2'

        // log4j-api and log4j-core
        implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.2'
        implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.2'

        // jul-to-slf4j
        implementation 'org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:2.0.0'
```

And excluded from the spring dependencies for conflicts avoiding:

```
//security
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${spring_boot_version}"){
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    ...............
```

I created a simple `log4j2.properties`:

```
# Set to debug or trace if log4j initialization is failing
status = warn

# Name of the configuration
name = ConsoleLogConfigDemo

# Console appender configuration
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger level
rootLogger.level = debug

# Root logger referring to console appender
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger
```

The properties works well - I can change format of the message and managing logger level.
I see correctly system logs in the console, but don't see custom logs:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class BusinessRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Hello Log4j!!!");
        SpringApplication.run(BusinessRunner.class);
    }
}
```

### The `Hello Log4j!!!` message isn't appears in the console.

Updated:

As I understand - this is impossible to use log4j trough Slf4j? May be anyone know another solution?